The collapse of the wave function in the early universe
If the wave function collapse is true then what in the early Universe observed things to create all of the different particles?

There is no such thing as wave function collapse (it's just an unfortunate term for irreversible energy exchange during a measurement process) and the universe does not have a wave function to begin with. Only systems of which we can make many independent copies can have something like a wave function.

The equations of motion of quantum theory don't include collapse. When information is copied out of a system that suppresses quantum interference - this is called decoherence:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282
As a result of decoherence large enough objects are decohered on scales of space and time much smaller than the scales on which they change significantly. A dust grain at room temperature will decohere in something like $10^{−18}s$ (Section 4.1.2 of the above reference). These objects behave according to classical physics to a good approximation, which may include acting a bit like a particle.
There is no need to invoke collapse or observation in quantum theory, so there is no need to worry about its implications anywhere including the early universe.
